# Function for reformatting multiple columns in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, reformatting

I have five data frames in `R` and in each of them I have a column titled `DOB` for date of birth and another column titled `StudentID` as well as other variables.  However, I would like a function that will reformat the `DOB` column in each data frame to be in this format `%m/%d/%y` and transforms the `DOB` variable into a character class variable. I would also like this same function to transform StudentID variable to numeric.

Is there a way to develop a function that accomplish the goals outlined above without affecting the other variables in the data set?

So far, I've just been doing the reformatting and converting manually with the code below:

```
df1$DOB<-as.Date(df1$DOB, format = "%m/%d/%y")
df1$DOB<-as.character(df1$DOB)
df1$StudentID <- as.numeric(df1$StudentID)

df2$DOB<-as.Date(df2$DOB, format = "%m/%d/%y")
df2$DOB<-as.character(df2$DOB)
df2$StudentID <- as.numeric(df2$StudentID)

df3$DOB<-as.Date(df3$DOB, format = "%m/%d/%y")
df3$DOB<-as.character(df3$DOB)
df3$StudentID <- as.numeric(df3$StudentID)

df4$DOB<-as.Date(df4$DOB, format = "%m/%d/%y")
df4$DOB<-as.character(df4$DOB)
df4$StudentID <- as.numeric(df4$StudentID)

df5$DOB<-as.Date(df5$DOB, format = "%m/%d/%y") 
df5$DOB<-as.character(df5$DOB)
df5$StudentID <- as.numeric(df5$StudentID)
```

Thank you for your help with this!

I haven't tried making a function for this yet because I'm not very good at making functions yet.

Comment: Please note, the Date type in R necessarily prints as `YYYY-MM-DD` ISO 8601. The `format` parameter tells `as.Date` that the data it is reading in is currently `%m/%d/%y`, but will not turn it into a Date with that format, which is what your description seems to describe as your goal. If your current data is already in Date format, you can use `format(df1$DOB, "%m/%d/%y")` to create a character string using that date format.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can give us some clues about what form your input is in. If you run `dput(df1$DOB)` that will create code that we can run to recreate the first six elements of `df1$DOB` in the form you have them.

Comment: Although I provided an answer below, I believe this may have a simpler solution, but for that please share the data and what exactly are we looking for in a solution.

Comment: "I would like a function that will reformat the DOB column in each data frame to be in this format `%m/%d/%y`" -- I don't think your current code accomplishes this, does it? It seems to take `%m/%d/%y` character data, convert it to Date (`%Y-%m-%d`) and save that as character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can put the data.frames in a list and call function in a loop:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data_frames <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

my_function <- function(df) {
    df %>%
    mutate(DOB = as.character(as.Date(DOB, format = "%m/%d/%y")),
           StudentId = as.numeric(StudentId))
    }


lapply(my_data_frames, my_function)
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks!  This code only missing a parenthetical needed to close the "mutate" code function